# Help on probability distribution question

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let a random variable $X$ take its values in the set $\{-2, -1, 1, 2, 3\}$. Assume
that its pmf function can be written in the form:
$$
P(X = x_i)= 
\begin{cases}
    \frac{x_i^2}{a},& \text{if } x_i\in\{-2, -1, 1, 2, 3\}\\
    0,              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Find the constant $a$.

I'm not sure where to even start.

Comment: If you're not sure where to start, you may want to take a look at some basic properties of PMF: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function. Particularly the three properties listed on the wiki page.

Comment: You want all probabilities of events to be non-negative and the total probability to be  $1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sum of $x^2/a$ over your set is $19/a$. For this to be a pmf the sum must equal $1$, so $a=19$.